# Cron error on Debian11 cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly

Tags: debian

I just reinstalled a new OS on my VPS to Debian 11.

Now I get the bellow error whenever the automated cron.hourly runs

```
/sbin/run-parts: line 5: 127011 127011: syntax error in expression (error token is "127011")
```

and when I check the file `/sbin/run-parts`.

I see the below code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

parameters="$@"
ip=$(hostname -i)
**RANDOM=${ip//./}**
test -z "${parameters##*/etc/cron.*}" &&
        sleep $((RANDOM % 3600))

exec /bin/run-parts "$@"
```

Line 5, `**RANDOM=${ip//./}**`  is the problem, what could be the issue with line 5?

Comment: Remove the asterisks, they would cause a problem. Unless you added them yourself to the answer for highlighting? It isn't clear. Please quote `/sbin/run-parts` as it *actually* appears, without added highlighting. The line `RANDOM=${ip//./}` works (I've just checked it), as it just strips the periods `.` from the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

That something fishy with this script... <sup>(as it was mentioned, variable `RANDOM` must not be surrounded by asterisks characters, my guess you put it for highlighting error, but anyway there are twisted logic)</sup>

- first of all vanilla Debian 11 having program `run-parts` inside of directory `/usr/bin` (or its symlink inside `/bin`). It isn't a `/sbin/run-parts` on Debian 11.
- the second, `run-parts` is executable ELF file, not a bash script
- and the last, it really weird script and I doubt it is official one from  debian

P.S.
If it is yours script, - don't use reserved variable names such as `RANDOM`, rename it at least to `iRANDOM`, but keep in mind, that POSIX says that all caps variables should be used for environment only.

Comment: It is not a script from any package, but obviously it aims to randomize the execution time of the hourly, daily, weekly and/or monthly cron jobs. But as long as the IP address of the system does not change, the added delay does never change either. But having this on different systems with different IP addresses has the effect that those run their cron jobs at different times, which can be reasonable in cases. However, adjusting `/etc/crontab` would be much simpler and more explicit to achieve this ;).

Comment: @MichaIng that's exactly why I said - "That something fishy with this script." because it isn't standard one and it abusing reserved variable `RANDOM`

Comment: Generally it is fine and intended to use cron with custom scripts. Many packages use cron as well for cleanup and maintenance tasks, but this doesn't mean that it's meant to be used exclusively by distro packages. I didn't know about `RAMDOM` until now, indeed `echo $RANDOM` in bash seems to print a random integer between 0 and 50000. But I also recognised that assigning any value like `RANDOM=123` is simply ignored in bash. This means the script does what it aims and the variable assignment can be simply removed instead of fixed.

Comment: Ah nope, assigning a value has an effect, but the result does not match the assigned value. The following returns always the same 10 different values: `RANDOM=123; for i in {1..10}; do echo $RANDOM; done`. It's like assigning a value (re)sets a starting point for `RANDOM` from which it is then varied time based or so. However, I'm drifting off topic.